# GCP Fetch Public IP address for compute instance created from google_compute_instance_template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

How can I fetch public IP address for compute instances created by google_compute_instance_template using terraform.

[google_compute_instance_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template#argument-reference)
There is no attribute to get name of the compute instances created . I can see only name_prefix which will be suffixed with some random string.

I was thinking of using [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance) data source which as attribute `network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip` , but it requires compute instance name.
eg.

```
data "google_compute_instance" "appserver" {
  name = "primary-application-server"
  zone = "us-central1-a"
}
```

Below is the code I am using , I am attaching compute instance group manager to the backend service of a load balancer.
I need the public ip of the instance for connecting to SQL database

```
resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "mig" {
  project = var.project
  name    = "${var.name}-instance-group"
  region  = var.region
  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.instance_template.id
    name              = "primary"
  }
  
  named_port {
    name = "https"
    port = 443
  }
  base_instance_name = "${var.name}-mig"
  target_size        = var.instance_count
}
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "instance_template" {
  name_prefix             = "${var.name}-instance"
  project                 = var.project
  machine_type            = var.machine_type
  labels                  = var.labels
  tags                    = local.firewall_rules.target_tags
  can_ip_forward          = var.can_ip_forward
  metadata_startup_script = file("${path.module}/${var.startup_script}")
  region                  = var.region
  #min_cpu_platform        = var.min_cpu_platform
  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = local.all_disks
    content {
      auto_delete  = lookup(disk.value, "auto_delete", null)
      boot         = lookup(disk.value, "boot", null)
      device_name  = lookup(disk.value, "device_name", null)
      disk_name    = lookup(disk.value, "disk_name", null)
      disk_size_gb = lookup(disk.value, "disk_size_gb", lookup(disk.value, "disk_type", null) == "local-ssd" ? "375" : null)
      disk_type    = lookup(disk.value, "disk_type", null)
      interface    = lookup(disk.value, "interface", lookup(disk.value, "disk_type", null) == "local-ssd" ? "NVME" : null)
      mode         = lookup(disk.value, "mode", null)
      source       = lookup(disk.value, "source", null)
      source_image = lookup(disk.value, "source_image", null)
      type         = lookup(disk.value, "disk_type", null) == "local-ssd" ? "SCRATCH" : "PERSISTENT"
      #labels       = lookup(disk.value, "disk_labels", {}) 

      dynamic "disk_encryption_key" {
        for_each = compact([var.disk_encryption_key == null ? null : 1])
        content {
          kms_key_self_link = var.disk_encryption_key
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "service_account" {
    for_each = [var.service_account]
    content {
      email  = lookup(service_account.value, "email", null)
      scopes = lookup(service_account.value, "scopes", null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "network_interface" {
    for_each = var.network_interfaces
    iterator = config
    content {
      network    = config.value.network
      subnetwork = "projects/${var.project}/regions/${var.region}/subnetworks/${config.value.subnetwork}"
      network_ip = try(config.value.addresses.internal, null)
      dynamic "access_config" {
        for_each = config.value.nat ? [""] : []
        content {
          nat_ip = try(config.value.addresses.external, null)
        }
      }
      dynamic "alias_ip_range" {
        for_each = local.network_interface_options[config.key].alias_ips != null ? local.network_interface_options[config.key].alias_ips : {}
        iterator = config_alias
        content {
          subnetwork_range_name = config_alias.key
          ip_cidr_range         = config_alias.value
        }
      }
      nic_type = local.network_interface_options[config.key].nic_type
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = "true"
  }

  # scheduling must have automatic_restart be false when preemptible is true.
  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = !var.options.preemptible
    on_host_maintenance = local.on_host_maintenance
    preemptible         = var.options.preemptible
  }

  dynamic "shielded_instance_config" {
    for_each = var.shielded_config != null ? [var.shielded_config] : []
    iterator = config
    content {
      enable_secure_boot          = config.value.enable_secure_boot
      enable_vtpm                 = config.value.enable_vtpm
      enable_integrity_monitoring = config.value.enable_integrity_monitoring
    }
  }

  dynamic "confidential_instance_config" {
    for_each = var.confidential_compute ? [""] : []
    content {
      enable_confidential_compute = true
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you create the VMs by using the template? Can you show that snippet?

Comment: Did you check this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-ip-address#api)?

Comment: I have added the code for google compute template.

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez I am trying to find the public ip via terraform.

Comment: @FerreginaPelona - were you able to check, or need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by the following:

```
#Get the list of instances
data "google_compute_region_instance_group" "mig_data" {
    name = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.mig.name
    region = var.region
}

#Get each instance data 
data "google_compute_instance" "intance_data" {
  count = length(data.google_compute_region_instance_group.mig_data.instances)
  self_link = data.google_compute_region_instance_group.mig_data.instances[count.index].instance
}

#Print the data needed
output "public_ips" {
  value = [
    for instance in data.google_compute_instance.intance_data: 
    [
      instance.name, instance.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
    ]
  ]
}
```

Basically we need to get the list of instances created in the MIG using the [`data.google_compute_region_instance_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_region_instance_group#attributes-reference) and then iterate over this list to get the data for each instance.

I'm using `output` just to print the IPs but of course you can use those values in any other resource if you want.